# how can i make it so every time i click a button on tkinter, it outputs the next line on a list

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I've been trying to make some small projects to get me started on Tkinter and i wanted to make a set of rules in which it outputs the next rule whenever you click a button. Please help i have no clue on how to do this.

Basically i tried something that was almost definitely wrong when i typed it despite my limited knowledge. it was 10 lines of rules in which i tried to put into a list and use a function to execute each one. Didn't really work out as you can tell.

```
from tkinter import *

rules=Tk()
rules.title("Rules")
rules.geometry("200x200")

def click():
    rule_label1 = rule_label1(rules, text=("rule1"))
    rule_label2 = rule_label2(rules, text=("rule2"))
    rule_label3 = rule_label3(rules, text=("rule3"))
    rule_label4 = rule_label4(rules, text=("rule4"))
    rule_label5 = rule_label5(rules, text=("rule5"))
    rule_label6 = rule_label6(rules, text=("rule6"))
    rule_label7 = rule_label7(rules, text=("rule7"))
    rule_label8 = rule_label8(rules, text=("rule8"))
    rule_label9 = rule_label9(rules, text=("rule9"))
    rule_label10 = rule_label10(rules, text=("rule10"))                      
    
button = Button(rules, text="Click for next line", font="calibri", padx=50, pady=50, command=click, fg="red", bg="Green")
button.pack()

rules.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put the rules in a list, and put the current list index in a global variable. When you click on the button, increment the index and display that element of the list.

Comment: `rule_label1 = rule_label1(...)` doesn't make much sense. You shouldn't have a variable with the same name as a function.

Comment: Did you mean `rule_label1 = Label(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

1. Start by moving your rules to a list; I'll call it `rule_texts`.
2. Create the label (`rule_label`) that will display the text and initialize it to the first entry of the list (`rule_texts[0]`).
3. Initialize `i = 1`; this index will refer to the index of we're accessing from `rule_texts`.
4. Define `click()` which sets the `rule_label` to the `i`th index of `rule_texts`, then increments `i` by 1.
5. (Suggested) Add handling for when you reach the end of the `rule_text` list.

```
from tkinter import *

rules = Tk()
rules.title("Rules")
rules.geometry("1000x200")

rule_texts = [
    "The rules are quite simple",
    "You get to roll two dice. The total score of the dice is added onto your personal score so for example, if you roll a 5 and a 6, you would get 11",
    "If the total that you get is an even number then excellent because you get an extra 10 points",
    "Bad news if your total is an add number though because that is -5 points",
    "Double rolls allow you to roll an extra dice which is also added onto your total",
    "Scores cannot go below 0 at any point",
    "There will be 5 rounds and the person whose total is the highest wins",
    "In the rare case of a tie, a single dice roll will decide who wins overall",
    "Enjoy!!!",
    "You can now close this screen.",
]

rule_label = Label(
    rules,
    text=rule_texts[0],
    font="calibri",
    padx=50,
    pady=50,
    fg="black",
)
rule_label.pack()


i = 1


def click():
    global i
    rule_label.config(text=rule_texts[i])
    i += 1
    # if i == len(rule_texts):
        # button.config(state=DISABLED)
        # button.destroy()


button = Button(
    rules,
    text="Click for next line",
    font="calibri",
    padx=50,
    pady=50,
    command=click,
    fg="red",
    bg="Green",
)
button.pack()


rules.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yield` and a **generator opbject**:
I changed the pack() to grid() layout and use a Text() widget, instead of a Label() widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Rules")
root.geometry("655x500")

top_frame = tk.Frame(root)
top_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

error_count_list = []
def generator(option_list):
    for i in range(len(option_list)):
        #print(option_list[i])
        tex.delete("1.0", "end")
        tex.insert( f"{i}.0", option_list[i])
        yield 

        
options = ["\nThe rules are quite simple",
            "\nYou get to roll two dice. The total score of the dice is added onto your personal score so for example, if you roll a 5 and a 6, you would get 11",
            "\nIf the total that you get is an even number then excellent because you get an extra 10 points",
            "\nBad news if your total is an add number though because that is -5 points",
            "\nDouble rolls allow you to roll an extra dice which is also added onto your total",
            "\nScores cannot go below 0 at any point",
            "\nThere will be 5 rounds and the person whose total is the highest wins",
            "\nIn the rare case of a tie, a single dice roll will decide who wins overall",
            "\nEnjoy!!!\n\n"]

iterator = generator(options)

def click():
    try:
        next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        tex.delete("1.0", "end")
        tex.insert( tk.END, "You can now close this screen!", 'warning')
        #print("You can now close this screen.")
        print("Button will close the app, after 3 times empty text!")
        error_count_list.append(1)
    finally:
        if len(error_count_list)>2:
            root.destroy()
            
tex = tk.Text(top_frame)
tex.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew', padx=5, pady=5)
tex.tag_config('warning', foreground="red")
    
button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Click for next line", font="calibri", padx=50, pady=50, command=click, fg="blue", bg="lightgreen")
button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ew', padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your requirement. As you want to close the window after reading all the rules, I assume that the window you say about here is a popup window.

So, I guess that your project's algorithm is as follows.

1. There will be a main window containing the game. This main window starts with a 'Read Rules' button.
2. If you click the 'Read Rules' button, a window pops out. This pop-up window contains the rules of the game.
3. But all the rules are not displayed at a stretch. As you click the button provided in the popup window, Rules are displayed one by one - one rule at a time and next rule by clicking the button 'next rule'

Though we all know that rules should be made into a list, this is bit tricky as the index of the list should increment for every click of the 'next rule' button. So, I understand your problem.

This is my code with explanation provided then and there(works perfect):

```
from tkinter import *

#function initiate() triggered by the button 'read rules' in main window
def initiate():

    #declare cnt as global variable
    global cnt
    #make cnt=1, because 1 will be added in later step during stepup()
    cnt = -1
    
    #run popup() to open popup window
    popup()
    

#function stepup() triggered by the button 'read rules' in the popup window
def stepup():

    #need the global variable cnt & will continue to use
    global cnt
    cnt = cnt + 1
    
    #run click() to read next rule
    click() 
    
   

    
def click():
    #need the global variable cnt & will continue to use
    global cnt
    
    
    
    '''
    1. list of rules created
    
    2. Each rule's length can not exceed the width of popup window.
    so, instead of double quotes, triple quotes used as when required
    
    3. First rule is remmoved from the list as it is the default text
    '''
    rule_list = [
             
             '''You get to roll two dice. The total score of 
the dice is added onto your personal score so for
example, if you roll a 5 and a 6, you would get 11''',
'''If the total that you get is an even number then
excellent because you get an extra 10 points''',
'''Bad news if your total is an add number though
because that is -5 points''',
'''Double rolls allow you to roll an extra dice
which is also added onto your total''',
"Scores cannot go below 0 at any point",
'''There will be 5 rounds and the person whose
total is the highest wins''',
'''In the rare case of a tie, a single dice
roll will decide who wins overall''',
"Enjoy!!!\nYou can now close this screen."
             ]
             
             
         
    L = len(rule_list)
    

    
    #close popup once finished reading
    if cnt==L: rules.destroy()
    
    #show the rules taking cnt as index of the list
    else: rule_label.configure(text = rule_list[cnt])
        
    
    
    
def popup():

    #global rule_label as rule text will be triggered by another function
    global rule_label
    #need the global variable cnt & will continue to use
    global cnt
    #popup wndw name is rules -made as global as it will be closed by another function
    global rules
    rules = Toplevel(root)
    rules.geometry('500x500')
    rules.title('Rules')
    fr = Frame(rules, width=500,height=400)
    fr.pack(side='top')
    
    #first rule is made as default text for rule_label
    rule_label = Label(fr,font='12',text="The rules are quite simple")
    rule_label.pack(side='top')
    
    #button triggering function stepup()
    rule_btn = Button(rules, text='Next Rule', command=stepup)
    rule_btn.pack(side='bottom')
  

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title('Game')

#read rules button triggers initiate() which inturn opens popup window 
Button(root, text= 'Read Rules', command=initiate).pack(side='top')

root.mainloop()
```